# Spawning language server with cmd: `lua-language-server`

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, vim-plugins, lua

I've recently transferred from [Packer](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim) plugin manager to [Lazy](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim).

Utilizing LSP, [LspConfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig), [Mason](https://github.com/williamboman/mason.nvim), [MasonLspConfig](https://github.com/williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim) with several language servers for programming.

The problem is that Neovim is having troubles accessing these servers. It worked with the Packer package manager. Maybe I misconfigured something, but I'm clueless what the issue might be.

The language servers are installed and added to PATH.

```
Spawning language server with cmd: `lua-language-server` failed with error message: EACCES: permission denied
```

"lua-language-server" command as such is callable.

I'm using [Fish shell](https://fishshell.com/) as a default shell.

Here is my plugin configuration file:

```
return {
    { "lvimuser/lsp-inlayhints.nvim" },
    { 
        "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
        dependencies = { "lvimuser/lsp-inlayhints.nvim" },
        config = function()
          local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")

          lspconfig.gopls.setup({
            on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
              require("settings/shared").on_attach(client, bufnr)
              require("lsp-inlayhints").setup({
                inlay_hints = {
                  type_hints = {
                    prefix = "=> "
                  },
                },
              })
              require("lsp-inlayhints").on_attach(client, bufnr)
              require("illuminate").on_attach(client)
            end,
            settings = {
              gopls = {
                analyses = {
                  nilness = true,
                  unusedparams = true,
                  unusedwrite = true,
                  useany = true,
                },
                experimentalPostfixCompletions = true,
                gofumpt = true,
                staticcheck = true,
                usePlaceholders = true,
                hints = {
                  assignVariableTypes = true,
                  compositeLiteralFields = true,
                  compositeLiteralTypes = true,
                  constantValues = true,
                  functionTypeParameters = true,
                  parameterNames = true,
                  rangeVariableTypes = true,
                }
              },
            },
      })
      end
    },

    { "williamboman/mason.nvim" },
    { "Afourcat/treesitter-terraform-doc.nvim" },
    { "williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim", 
        dependencies = { "williamboman/mason.nvim" },
        config = function()
            local mason_lspconfig = require("mason-lspconfig")

            mason_lspconfig.setup({
                PATH = "prepend",
                ensure_installed = {
                  "eslint",
                  "gopls", -- WARNING: This could be an issue with goenv switching.
                  "marksman",
                  "rust_analyzer",
                  "sumneko_lua",
                  "terraformls",
                  "tflint",
                  "tsserver",
                  "yamlls",
                }
            })

            mason_lspconfig.setup_handlers({
                function(server_name)
                    require("lspconfig")[server_name].setup({
                    on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
                        require("settings/shared").on_attach(client, bufnr)
                        require("illuminate").on_attach(client)

                        if server_name == "terraformls" then
                        require("treesitter-terraform-doc").setup()
                        end
                    end
                  })
                end
                })
            end
            },

  { "simrat39/symbols-outline.nvim",
    config = function()
      require("symbols-outline").setup({
        -- autofold_depth = 1, -- h: close, l: open, W: close all, E: open all
        auto_close = false,
        highlight_hovered_item = true,
        position = "left",
        width = 15,
        symbols = {
          File = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxAqua" }, -- TSURI
          Module = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxBlue" }, -- TSNamespace
          Namespace = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxBlue" }, -- TSNamespace
          Package = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxBlue" }, -- TSNamespace
          Class = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxGreen" }, -- TSType
          Method = { icon = "ƒ", hl = "GruvboxOrange" }, -- TSMethod
          Property = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxOrange" }, -- TSMethod
          Field = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxRed" }, -- TSField
          Constructor = { icon = "", hl = "TSConstructor" },
          Enum = { icon = "ℰ", hl = "GruvboxGreen" }, -- TSType
          Interface = { icon = "ﰮ", hl = "GruvboxGreen" }, -- TSType
          Function = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxYellow" }, -- TSFunction
          Variable = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxPurple" }, -- TSConstant
          Constant = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxPurple" }, -- TSConstant
          String = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxGray" }, -- TSString
          Number = { icon = "#", hl = "TSNumber" },
          Boolean = { icon = "⊨", hl = "TSBoolean" },
          Array = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxPurple" }, -- TSConstant
          Object = { icon = "⦿", hl = "GruvboxGreen" }, -- TSType
          Key = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxGreen" }, -- TSType
          Null = { icon = "NULL", hl = "GruvboxGreen" }, -- TSType
          EnumMember = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxRed" }, -- TSField
          Struct = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxGreen" }, -- TSType
          Event = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxGreen" }, -- TSType
          Operator = { icon = "+", hl = "TSOperator" },
          TypeParameter = { icon = "", hl = "GruvboxRed" } --TTSParameter
        },
      })
    end
  },

  { "mfussenegger/nvim-lint",
    config = function()
      local lint = require("lint")
      lint.linters_by_ft = {
        go = { "golangcilint" }, -- ~/.golangci.yml
      }
      -- see ./lsp.lua for calls to this plugin's try_lint() function.
    end
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After I rebooted the system, the lsp-config detected the `lua-language-server`.
My guess is that the PATH wasn't properly sourced.

For anyone having similar issues - make sure you have the language servers installed, added to the PATH correctly, and don't forget to source your config file with variables.

Here are my variables for the `lua-language-server` and `gopls` server in the fish shell format:

```
# Lua
set -gx PATH ~/.config/lsp/lua-language-server/bin $PATH

# Go
set -gx GOPATH ~/go
set -gx PATH /usr/local/go/bin $PATH
set -gx PATH $GOPATH/bin $PATH
```

And here they are in the bash format:

```
# Lua
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.config/lsp/lua-language-server/bin

# Go
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```